# Statistical test on pairs of percentages

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I am quantifying a measure of correlation in a graph/network under two different experimental conditions to determine whether there is a significant difference in the measure given by the change of condition. I am repeating this computation for a number (N=5) of heterogeneous graphs/networks in the sense that they may have different number of nodes/links. To avoid any dependency on these graphs/networks I am normalizing each measure by the summation of both measures under each condition.  I am now simply using a t-test between both sets of proportions because of the limited number of samples, but I have concerns given the nature of my computations. Which statistical test would be more convenient in this case?

Comment: Could you clarify what the numerator and denominator are in your response variable?

Comment: The numerator is the measure under each binary condition and the denominator is the sum of both measures.

Comment: Is the measure some kind of count?

Comment: The measure is the sum of pairwise correlations between connected nodes within a graph.

Comment: The two values will be perfectly negatively correlated.

Comment: Yes, then could a paired t-test be used between both sets of proportions?

Comment: There's no more information in the difference than in a single value: if $x_1+x_2 =1$, then $x_1-x_2 =2x_1-1$. The difference has the same information about location difference as $x_1$ alone. There's no benefit in doing a paired test.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Glen. In this context, I guess that one could just test whether one set of proportions is strictly larger than one half.

Comment: You could, but you have the additional complication that continuous proportions won't have constant variance - proportions near 0 or 1 will tend to have smaller variance than proportions near 1/2. So the assumption of constant variance may be problematic. That said, it may not be such an issue for your data. If the proportions within the first group are reasonably consistent, it may be less of an issue.